# HOG descriptor implementation in c++

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, svm

I would like to know if there is a clean implementation of the HOG descriptor in c++ besides the opencv implementation.

I think I could learn more about the process if I found a simple c++ implementation. Any hints appreciated.

Comment: the process is just (radius 1): for each pixel: for each neighbor: test whether it is bigger than the neighbor. Encode the whole information in a single byte per pixel.

Comment: @Micka this sounds like the description of local binary patterns, not HOG

Comment: sure you are right, I just misread -.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is surprisingly in the Matlab toolbox called [Piotr's toolbox](https://github.com/pdollar/toolbox). Although it is a matlab library, the core functions are written in C with the mex interface. Check out the file gradientMex.cpp under the channels directory - it contains both the gradient orientation and accumulation into histograms in many variations, including the one made popular by Pedro Felzenszwalb.